# Setting type of Imported Campaign

Tags: data, npsp

I am using NPSP Data Importer Template for importing contacts, accounts and campaigns. Everything works as expected, except that Campaigns are imported as Conference. Is there any way i can change that to email during import process?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the campaign record type or Type field value in the NPSP data import default process.

If you're referring to record type, the importing user can change their default record type for campaign in My Settings so that any campaign they create uses their own default.

If you're referring to the Type field, you can make a custom mapping using the [Advanced Mapping](https://powerofus.force.com/s/article/NPSP-Data-Import-Mapping-Methods) feature and then include the type in your import file.  You can do this with the record type ID field also.

BTW - the best resource for NPSP support is the [Power of Us Hub](https://powerofus.force.com/publogin).  You'll find other NPSP users, consultants, and Salesforce.org staff participating in many discussion groups.

Comment: Thanks David...